# What is /^image\/\w+/.test(file.type) doing step by step?

Tags: javascript, regex

I grabbed this bit of code I'm using to test if a file being placed into a canvas is an image or not. I'd like to know what this is actually doing. For reference, "file" is a FileList from the input.

```
if (/^image\/\w+/.test(file.type))
```

Comment: check if the `file.type` start with `image/`

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you not know what something of the form `/.../` means? Do you not know that that is a regular expression, but don't understand the `^` and `\/\w+` parts inside? Do you not know that `.test` invokes a method on some object? Do you not know the `test` method on regular expressions? Do you not understand how `file.type` works? Do you not understand why such a test would be being done, or what it means?

Comment: Thank you Mosh. Several steps I was not sure of torazaburo, I wasn't sure ^ was being used as "begins with", I did not know what the "w+" was for. As it was a short line of code, I was just hoping someone would go through it step by step. The answers below all add up to a complete answer, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^image\/\w+/` is a regex that matches "image/png" and "image/jpeg" and all other strings that begin with "image/".

`/^image\/\w+/.test(s)` tests if the given string s matches the regex.

`if (/^image\/\w+/.test(file.type))` checks if the file.type matches an image file type

Answer (score 0):

well

its a regular expression which tries to check file.type for certain pattern..

that pattern is

^ begin with this
^image .. begin with image,

\/ .. after image there should be a forward slash

\w+ means one or more alphanumeric characters or underscore after that

example 'image/abc' will match and 'image/' wont match